# How to Iterate over radio buttons in watir

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

Below is the code, that describes the radio button elements.

```
<div class="questionnaire_detail_question_body">
<div class="questionnaire_detail_answers">
                    <label class="radioinputwrapper">
                      <input class="questionnaire_detail_radiobutton" type="RADIO" value="Never">
                    </label>
                    <label class="radioinputwrapper">
                      <input class="questionnaire_detail_radiobutton" type="RADIO" value="Sometimes">
                    </label>
                    <label class="radioinputwrapper">
                      <input class="questionnaire_detail_radiobutton" type="RADIO" value="Often">
                    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried getting all the radio button under particular div and selected the option using the below code. Item is the list element to iterate over this

```
answers = item.div_element(class: 'questionnaire_detail_question_body')
                    .div_element(class: 'questionnaire_detail_answers').radio_button_elements
      answers.each do |input|
        if input.value.include? option
          input.click
          selected_option &&= input.set?
        end
      end
```

But while validating, whether the radio button is check or not using .set? or .checked?, I'm getting deprecation warning as

*** DEPRECATION WARNING**
 You are calling a method named set? at psc.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in psc_choose_selected_score'.
 **This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.**
 This feature will be removed in the near future.
 **Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.
*** If you are using functionality that does not exist in page-object please request it be added.

I tried using the methods mentioned in https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Elements, as select_option and option_selected?

My question is how to get rid of this deprecation warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for checking that a 
[`PageObject::Elements::RadioButton`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/PageObject/Platforms/WatirWebDriver/RadioButton) is selected is `selected?`:

```
input.selected?
```